# How to use Spring Boot but use Hibernate XML mapping files instead of annotations

Tags: spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot 2.0 and annotations on my Entities. I want to remove the annotations and switch to using XML configuration files for mapping my domain models to the database in order to remove any sign of the technology implementation from the domain models.

Problem is, I can't find how to configure spring boot to use the hibernate mapping files.

I am happy for Spring to set the database connection, but I want to manage the mappings via XML if possible.

Comment: And how is using hibernate specific XML not a sign of a technology implementing? Also JPA isn't an implementation that is a specification for which hibernate is an implementation. As long as you don't use hibernate specific annotations there is nothing binding you to any technology. But hibernate will detect additional mapping files (or the default `orm.xml` if you stick to JPA) on the root of the classpath or you can specify the list through configuration.

Answer (score 1):

On the off chance, I created the folder resources/hibernate and then created a mapping file user.hbm.xml, then removed the annotations from the entity class, and Spring appears to have automatically picked up the Hibernate XML file.

Comment: That is actually hibernate detecting those`*.hbm.xml` files and which are imho even more of a sign of implementing technology. You now made it harder to move to something like EclipseLink instead of Hibernate with that custom HBM file instead of standard annotations.

Comment: so you think JPA annotations on the domain objects is a more suitable approach?

Comment: I guess that would be a opinionated answer, you could also use the standardized `orm.xml` to specify the mapping (yes you can also express JPA mappings through XML instead of annotations). So if you truly want to remove it from the code you should use the `orm.xml` mapping instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to configure, you only need to put the *.hbm.xml files under the src/main/resources folder and Spring Boot can automatically scan for them.

In my test, i have put the Item.hbm.xml under /src/main/resources/hibnerate folder and i can successfully load the Item from the DB

Comment: Also, i checked you can also define the hbm files in the application.properties for the property: spring.jpa.mapping-resources. Example:
`spring.jpa.mapping-resources=hibernate/MyMapping.hbm.xml`

Comment: the automatic detection didn't work for me. I had to provide `spring.jpa.mapping-resources` property.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the `LocalSessionFactoryBean` to set the mappings locations. (see: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html)

Perhaps something like:

```
@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setMappingResources(...locations of your xml);
    //Other configutation omitted
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

could work.

note: I have not tested the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **LocalSessionFactoryBean** to create the **sessionfactory** bean then create the following property and keep all the *.hbm.xml files either inside the resource folder or in the classpath should solve the problem.

```
<property name="mappingResources">
  <list>
    <value>MyMapping.hbm.xml</value>
  </list>
</property>
```

**[More - SessionFactory setup in a Spring container](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/reference/orm.html)**